# Can't update silverlight web part

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight

After making changes to my custom Silverlight application, I can't get the Silverlight web part on my SharePoint site to reflect changes. I tried making a change and then opening the site in Firefox, and it did reflect the changes, while IE stayed the same. I made another change, and neither browser reflects the changes. I even tried deleting all the files under _layouts/ClientBin and still no changes.

Comment: I've also made sure blob caching is disabled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blob cache has nothing to do with this. It caches files from database on frontend servers. Your Silverlight application is already on the disk and would not benefit from caching.

If you've removed the file form `_layouts` folder, but you can still see the Silverlight app, it's probably cached by the browser. Browsers tend to be quite persistent when it comes to xap files.

`[Ctrl]+[Shift]+[Delete]` clears the cache in IE and Firefox. Make sure to select `Temporary internet files`/`Cache` and untick `Preserve favorites`.

I've been using this command in `Project properties->Build Events->Post-build event` in VS to clear the cache automatically:

```
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 8
```

Comment: Okay, this worked, but what I don't understand is why I only had to do it once. Now I can change it and redeploy it, and the changes are visible on refresh without clearing the cache again.

Comment: I also didn't do anything in firefox, and now the updates are showing on refresh as well.

Answer (score 0):

Did you "clean" your silverlight applet? right click on it, properties and delete all (not sure it's the right path). then after that, purge cache in IE and reload the page.